# Html5 Navigator not working in aspx, only in html page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I was taking a look at using the HTML5 Navigator, but it keeps throwing an error

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

This is my code for the aspx page...

```
var x = document.getElementById("Demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

This is all in the header of my aspx page. In the body I have a p tag with the id of Demo, that's where its throwing the error.

But when I use a regular HTML page it works fine, the only difference is that I put the script in the body.

So any idea on why its throwing the error in an aspx page?

Thanks

Comment: Unsure if the code above is complete - head vs body, is the dom element (Demo) loaded before your attempt to assign it to `x`?

Comment: I tried adding all my code but when I did it removed the html tags and stuff.. I'm unsure of what you mean...The paragraph tag is sitting in a div tag. I tried adding everything to the body and it threw the same error. I just tried adding the script after the form closing tag and it worked.

Comment: How you have define the `demo` element ?

Comment: @Aristos , I defined it a html paragraph tag and gave it the id of Demo

Comment: I had figured it out though, It seems I placed the script in the wrong area. Everything worked when I added the script to body. I think I should have used an if(document.ready()) when I had the script in the header.